# How to indicate a white text on the white background

Tags: fonts, ui-design, contrast

So I'm working on user interface where one can easily change different features (font color, font size etc.) for several tags/sections, mainly h1, h2, h3, text.

Everything works on-air so user has a preview  of changes at the 'preview-section' - which background is set from some variable - let's assume scenario, where background is **white**.

What is the best way to indicate user that he has white font on white background (because it looks like 'something-doesn't-work')?

```
<div class ='preview'>PREVIEW: 
<p>Hello white text!</p>
</div>
<div class ='preview-2'>PREVIEW: 
<p>Hello white text!</p>
</div>
<div class ='preview-3'>PREVIEW: 
<p class = 'indicate'>Hello white text! (is there a better way to indicate white text on white background, better than make it gray?)</p>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/orbroxmp/

I do not expect answers like 'make something with your background colour'. For some reason sometimes  it has to be white.

Thanks for help and have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought maybe instead of adding stroke to your font? In your css add

```
color: black;
 -webkit-text-fill-color: white; /* Will override color (regardless of order) */
 -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px; 
-webkit-text-stroke-color: black;
```

that way your text can stay white but the stroke still allows it to be viewable.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I wasn't aware of stroke - http://jsfiddle.net/orbroxmp/2/ I've updated my fiddle and it seems ok, but there are huge cons http://caniuse.com/#feat=text-stroke (doesn't work on firefox and ie10).

Comment: Agreed but this code should scale correctly woth ie and firefox, I would test myself but im away from the house for tje week.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the paragraph stroke as example paste this code in css from your programm

```
p {
   color: white;
   -webkit-text-fill-color: black; 
   -webkit-text-stroke-width: 1px;
   -webkit-text-stroke-color: black;
}
```